# What's the optimal way to run Druid on DC/OS?

Tags: mesos, dcos, druid

What's the best ways to run Druid on DC/OS?
I see there are 2 possible options; Marathon and Docker. Which one will you recommend? Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you talking about http://druid.io or something else?

Comment: `Docker` is a containerization technology and `Marathon` is a `Mesos Framework` which schedules services (a subset of which is containerized services) across a Mesos cluster. The better comparison would be `Docker Swarm v/s Marathon`, or `Druid in Docker Container v/s Druid in Mesos Containerizer` and so forth on these lines.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the best way to deploy Druid.io database on Mesos along with other components like spark, kafka...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Druid has quite a number of "moving" parts (5 if I counted correctly, plus ZK and eventually an external Postgres instance), it's not really easy to get it running in a completely automated way.

I started writing a framework (https://github.com/tobilg/druid-framework) by preparing Dockerfiles, but eventually stopped because of the complexity.

If you are ok with starting/managing the components manually, you can probably just run the Docker images via Marathon. But please keep in mind that this is IMO not a production-ready setup...

Comment: Thanks Tobi! I saw that DCOS has made packages for kafka, Spark, cassandra... I am thinking it will be easier if they create a Druid package that we could deploy using DCOS CLI?

Comment: The DC/OS packages are just frameworks... The work needs to be invested in any case.